# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property '_id' of null

Tags: node.js, express

Receiving this error and I've read so many posts with no avail. 

Any help would be greatly appreciated, as I've been trying to figure this out for so long!

```
(node:2225) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:2225) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

The line the error points to.

```
at /Users/[redacted/Desktop/prod/track-server/src/routes/trackRoutes.js:11:53
```

The code in question.

```
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const requireAuth = require('../middlewares/requireAuth');

const Track = mongoose.model('Track');
const router = express.Router();

router.use(requireAuth);

router.get('/tracks', async (req, res) => {
    const tracks = await Track.find({ userId: req.user._id });

    try {
        res.send(tracks);
    } catch (err) {
        res.status(422).send({ error: err.message });
    }
});

router.post('/tracks', async (req, res) => {
    const { name, locations } = req.body;

    if (!name || !locations) {
        return res.status(422).send({ error: 'You must provide a name and locations' });
    }

    try {
        const track = new Track({ name, locations, userId: req.user._id });
        await track.save();
        res.send(track);
    } catch (err) {
        res.status(422).send({ error: err.message });
    }
});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: `req.user` is `null`.  YOU have to figure out why that is.  Why do you think `req.user` would have anything in it?  That's not a standard field and you don't show any code that would set that propery.  Are you expecting to use `req.session.user` from an Express session object?  Or, are you expecting `requireAuth` to set it in your middleware?  If so, you need to show us that code.

Comment: Hey man, thanks for your response and I really appreciate the help. Was just hoping to minimize the code but you're right, in order to show everything, I think it's best to maybe just share my repo: https://github.com/neekyo/Track-Server

Comment: Well, I'd start by adding `console.log(req.user)` to the start of your `/tracks` route.  And, I'd add a `console.log(req.user)` to `requireAuth.js` right before it calls `next()`.  My best guess is that in `requireAuth.js`, when you do `const user = await User.findById(userId);`, you are getting `null` for `user`.  Perhaps you need to both code defensively for that and find out why it's doing that.  Also, EVERYWHERE you use `await`, you have to have a `try/catch` so you can catch errors.

Comment: thanks for your response! i thought i wrapped everything in a try/catch but I will go through it all tmw and also your suggestions, will update after! Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Well, you have explanation in error description. For some reason the user object in this code `req.user._id` is null. You have to trace why it is null and if you properly attach it to the request (guessing that in the requireAuth middleware?).

Comment: @jfriend00 I wrote "the `user` object" in the expression is null not that the whole expression is null

Comment: That's what I'm having trouble doing, and I really appreciate any help in advance. Here is my repo if you don't mind having a quick look: https://github.com/neekyo/Track-Server

Would it be as simple as changing req.user = user to req.user_.id in requireAuth?

Comment: You need to check the value of `user` after `await User.findById(userId);`. And the value of `userId`. You apparently dont extract a user. There might be a few reasons - there's is no such user in the database, the `userId` you are passing to the function is incorrect (and the error is caused by e.g.  the payload not having correct Id in the first place), or the async function works incorrectly as a whole, but it seems fine.

Comment: Also your Node client might not have rights to query the Users collection.

Comment: ahh thanks for your input, going to go through it all tmw! What do you mean by node not having DB query rights per se?

Comment: Well your db has some access restrictions. You connect to it from node as a user that has particular rights. If this user doesn't have rights to read from `users` collection then you will never find anything in the collection (but you might not get an error, just an empty result).